# Jquery: call to different function in same javascript file not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written an auto-complete code using jQuery in script tags in a given file.
In that I have various events like select open close etc. 
I want to call another function in the same file but not within the jQuery block. However this is not getting called.

```
$(function() { 
    function log( message ) {
        makeRequest(message);
    }     
    $("#searchArea").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: "callback",
                jsonpCallback: "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback",
                data: {
                    query: request.term
                },
                cache: true,
                url: "http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc"
            });

            YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback = function (data) {
                response($.map(data.ResultSet.Result, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.symbol+', '+item.name+'('+item.exchDisp+')',
                        value: item.symbol
                    }
                }));
            }
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#searchArea").val(ui.item.symbol);
            sendAcURL = "http://cs-server.usc.edu:29686/examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample?symbol="+ui.item.value;
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            log(sendAcURL);
        }
    });
});

function makeRequest(url) {
    alert("here");
}
```

I want to call makeRequest() through select event, but alert does not pop-up, hence my request is not called. Why is that so?

Comment: When asking for help, it's courteous to format your code readably (mark up all, rather than most, of it as "code", indent reasonably and consistently, etc.).

Comment: And you can create a [fiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce the problem

Comment: Is your console showing any error?

Comment: What was ur reason not to enclose the function inside the ready function?

Comment: @stackunderflow `$(handler)` is a shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(handler)`

Comment: Your basic logic for calling your handler and your other function seems to be find, http://jsfiddle.net/j7FA3/1/ check out your debugger to see if there is another error being thrown.

Comment: @Victory I know but my question was:  why he removed the function 'makeRequest()' out of the ready function

Comment: @stackunderflow : that's just the way my code is.basically in make request i am writing my ajax. the autocomplete is for user friendly behaviour. so on selecting an option from the dropdown of autocomplete i want to call the make request function.
 Sorry about the formatting, ill keep that in mind next time.

Comment: btw thanks guys i figured it out! i changed the code completely.